# Integrate CodeceptJS with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, automated-tests, codeceptjs

I want to update the test results of my CodeceptJS scripts in Azure DevOps. I have each test script created for corresponding test case in DevOps. Now I wan the test results to be updated directly in Azure  whenever I run the script.

Can someone please suggest me how to link CodeceptJS with Azure DevOps? Is there any API or Plugin available?

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? Could you accept below answer if it answered your question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is not a plugin available to associate js test scripts to test cases in DevOps.

Currently only Tests that use MSTest v2, NUnit, and xUnit frameworks can be associated with a test case workitem when using Visual Studio 15.9 Preview 2 or later. See document [What types of tests are supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#q-what-types-of-tests-are-supported).

However, you can use rest api to update the test case results in azure devops.

First, [create test plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops) to include the test cases work item

Second, call [Point list rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to list all the test points associated to your test cases

Then call [point update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api to update the test result.